# What does this fragment of code actually do?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to understand this fragment of a batch code, and i cant even imagine what it's really doing.

Im confused with this 3 lines:

```
echo @prompt set date=$d$_set time=$t$h$h$h > {a}.bat
%comspec% /e:2048 /c {a}.bat > {b}.bat
for %%v in ({b}.bat del) do call %%v {?}.bat
```

What do they do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really I don't know where do you find that example because seems a very OLD OLD OLD function for Win9x.

The first echo command prints the desired command in a file named "**{a}.bat**"
(The printed command sets a date and a hour in the OS)

The second command only executes the CMD (The CMD path is stored in **%comspec%** variable) with a environment size in bytes (**/E:xxxx**) passing the printed command inside of **{a}.bat** like an argument and prints the standard output in a second file (**{b}.bat**)

The third FOR command uses the second token (**del**) like a command with the dynamic operator **?** wich matches **0 or 1 character** so the loop executes a command loop like this:

```
del {a}.bat
del {b}.bat
```

I Hope this helped you.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, i was reading slowly trying to understand the code, a and yes you help me a lot, but i dont understand why it do that. isnt more simple to put something like:

Comment: echo @prompt set date=$d$_set time=$t$h$h$h

Comment: yes, I know it's a silly code, maybe is a sample code to show what things you can do and how to do it (In the strangest way lol).